# Bracketing where clause in multiple use of AND & OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server using Multiple AND & OR

For example
MY QUESTION is should I put open and close bracket in OR statement between  ProductCode1, ProductCode2 & ProductCode3.

The reason I am asking is. Each time I put bracket and run the query I get a different result when the bracket is removed from it?

```
SELECT ProdID, 
       Productname,  
       SalesDate,  
       ProductCode1,
       ProductCode2
FROM Product_Table
WHERE  SalesDate >= ‘2015-01-01’
    AND  Productname IN (‘CA’,’DC’,’BF’,’GH’,’TQR’,’VXT’)
     AND ProductCode1  IN (232, 878, 287, 986, 672)
     OR ProductCode2 IN (213, 543, 971, 435,627)
     OR ProductCode3 IN (32, 89,67,45)
```

Comment: it depends on what your conditions for filtering are.

Comment: Personally, I use brackets every time I combine ANDs and ORs in a WHERE clause, for clarity if and when someone else reads the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is Operator Precedence .. which defines in what order the operators are evaluated. In the SQL dialects (and actually in every programming language) I know, the AND operator has higher priority than the OR operator. However, order in which the operators are evaluated can be controlled by using parenthesises:

When compared to your example (with conditions A to E), the expression:

```
A AND B AND C OR D OR E
```

is equivalent to the following expression:

```
(A AND B AND C) OR D OR E
```

Which means, that one of the following must be true:

- A and B and C
- or D
- or E

But according to your example, you'd probably want something like this:

```
A AND B AND (C OR D OR E)
```

Translated to your query, it would look like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Product_Table
WHERE  SalesDate >= ‘2015-01-01’
    AND  Productname IN (‘CA’,’DC’,’BF’,’GH’,’TQR’,’VXT’)
    AND (ProductCode1  IN (232, 878, 287, 986, 672)
        OR ProductCode2 IN (213, 543, 971, 435,627)
        OR ProductCode3 IN (32, 89,67,45))
```

So A and B must be true, and either C, D or E must also  be true. Translated to your example this would look like:

This is, for example, a complete list of all operators in a particular version of TSQL and their precedences: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the intent of your query is to find records that have a SalesDate greater than or equal to '2015-01-01' AND have a Productname in the set listed AND have one of the productCode fields' values match the sets you've specified. In that case, you need to group all the productCode filters together using parentheses.

```
   SELECT ProdID, 
           Productname,  
           SalesDate,  
           ProductCode1,
           ProductCode2
    FROM Product_Table
    WHERE  SalesDate >= ‘2015-01-01’
        AND  Productname IN (‘CA’,’DC’,’BF’,’GH’,’TQR’,’VXT’)
         AND (ProductCode1  IN (232, 878, 287, 986, 672)
              OR ProductCode2 IN (213, 543, 971, 435,627)
              OR ProductCode3 IN (32, 89,67,45))
```

This is a very basic component of using AND and OR operators. I'm struggling to find a good resource for you that explains it well, but [[maybe this will help]](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp).[1](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)